# gigya plugins with site login

Tags: gigya

I am using a Gigya plugin (ratings/reviews) with site login rather than social login but the plugin will not recognize the logged in user after I log a user in with socialize.notifyLogin(). The response I receive indicates that Gigya knows about the user and recognizes the user as logged in but the plug-in still renders in a logged out version. I am assuming this is a common scenario but have not found any samples that do this. Is there a call I need to make to notify the plug-in that a user is logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to send userinfo object:

```
ex:userInfo: { firstName: "David", gender: "m", age:30 }
```

Read more [here](http://developers.gigya.com/020_Client_API/010_Socialize/socialize.notifyLogin).